# How to prevent github file changes?

Tags: javascript, git, github, git-merge

I have a github repo where I have two branches.

- master branch // has production keys and variables
- dev branch // has development keys

On the dev branch a lot of the components have development keys and API urls defined, while the same files on the main branch have production level keys and API urls. Every update is pushed first to the dev branch and after QA to the main branch(and lastly to live env). The issue I'm facing is that every time I create pull request from dev into main these keys are overwritten( even if components with keys were not updated still pr sees as these files different and overrides main production keys). How can I prevent components with dev values from being in the pull request when they haven't been updated?

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you an out-of-the-box solution that is more conventional in the industry.

Any Value that you want to be branch specific should be picked as an ENVIRONMENT variable. Using environment variables you can totally keep things separate at the infrastructure level.

For example:

1. You want to deploy the dev branch to development env so in dev ec2 or container you can read, variables from the environment and you do not have it inside the code.
2. Same goes for production, you can get those values from env and not from code so your code remains the same because of the environment variable and you do not face the issue of keeping things different in two branches.

Also, you do not have to keep sensitivity keys, passwords, or other credentials in git. It should be handled at the infrastructure level.